# Convert an array to a nested object

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
var res = {}
var value = "Hello"
for(var i=a.length; i > 0; i-- ){
  var item = a[i-1]
  var temp = {}
  temp[item] = i == a.length ? value : {}
  if(i != a.length){
    Object.keys(res).forEach(r => {
      temp[item][r] = res[r]
    })
  }
  res = temp
}

console.log(res)
```

The result is :

```
{
  "a": {
    "b": {
      "c": {
        "d": "Hello"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Which is right, exactly what I need. I was just wondering if I'm doing it the right way or is there any better solutions for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are currently mixing declarative and functional style. I suggest succinct functional style:

```
var keys = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
var value = "Hello";
var res = keys.reduceRight((value, key) => ({[key]: value}), value);
```

Comment: Beautiful solution. Thank you so much for this. 

Answer (score 3):

I think, iterating the `array` once in the reverse order will be easy to create the nested `object` from array.

Steps:

**1.** Iterate the array in reverse order.

**2.** If index is equal to the length of array then assign the value to that key.

**3.** For all other cases simply put the previous object inside the new key.

Check this:

```js
var a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
var res = {};
var value = "Hello";

for(let i = a.length - 1; i >= 0 ; i--){
  if(i == a.length - 1)
    res = { [a[i]] : value};        // assign the value
  else
    res = { [a[i]] : res};          //put the prev object
}

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 2):

- Declare your variables outside the loop (or use `let` inside the loop).
- The checking `i > 0` in the for loop is unnecessary as `i--` will be falsy when it gets to zero anyway. This also allows you to use i as the array index instead of `i-1`
- Add commas and semi-colons where appropriate.

```js
var 
  a = ["a", "b", "c", "d"],
  res = {},
  value = "Hello",
  item, temp;
  
for(var i=a.length; i--; ){
  item = a[i], temp = {} ;
  temp[item] = i == a.length-1 ? value : {} ;
  if(i != a.length){
    Object.keys(res).forEach(r => {
      temp[item][r] = res[r] ;
    })
  }
  res = temp ;
}

console.log(res) ;
```